# Class definition in header file issues

Tags: c++

I am receiving the following error from the compiler
./include.list.h(22) error: identifier "input" is undefined.

Here is the header file where I explicitly define input-

```
#ifndef INIT_H
#define INIT_H

#include "list.h"

class input{

public:

 //** thermo variables **//
  int N;
  double nddensity;
  double ndtemp;  
  double ndvol;
  double ndside;
  double ndsideh;

  // ** force field variables** //
  double eps;
  double sigma;
  double rcut;
  double rv;
  double rcut2;
  double rv2;
  double rcrv2;

  input();


};

void print(input &);
double randomnumber();
void  position(list &, input &, int flag);


#endif
```

In init.cpp, I have the class initialization:

> input:: input() {
>
> ```
> //** thermo variables **//
> N = 500;
> nddensity =.8;
> ndtemp = 2.0;  
> ndvol = N/nddensity;
> ndside = pow(ndvol,1.0/3.0);
> ndsideh = ndside/2;
>
>
> // ** force field variables** //
> eps = 1;
> sigma = 1;
> rcut = 2.5;
> rv = 1.1*rcut;
> rcut2 = rcut*rcut;
> rv2 = rv*rv;
> rcrv2 = (rv-rcut)*(rv-rcut);
>  }
> ```

I can't seem to figure out why input would be undefined to void print. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `#include "init.h"` in `init.cpp`?

Answer (score 1):

You include `list.h` *before* the class definition, so it's not available in that header. According to the error message, something in `list.h` needs a declation of the class.

You don't need a full definition of `list` here, so replace the `#include` with a forward declaration

```
class list;
```

Within `list.h`, you probably need a similar declaration of `input`; or it might be necessary to include `init.h` if the header does something complicated with it.

Comment: I don't think I am following. Why is the way I am handling list.h affecting how void position is seeing the class input when position and input are in the same header file?

Comment: Also just out of curiousity, when I include list.h doesn't that tell the compiler to look in list.h for the definition of list?

Comment: @user3225087: More or less; it tells the compiler to include the entirety of that header (which presumably includes the definition of `list`) at that point. As the compiler says, something in that uses the name `input`, which isn't declared until after `list.h` is included.

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency.

You can forward declare the other class, but this is still a poor design.  Better to just do away with the circular dependency altogether.  At second glance, do you even need to include `list.h`?  Where are you using anything declared in it?

Comment: @unxnut: Oh, derp, one more line.  Thanks.

Comment: list.h includes a class list. void position is init.h takes in a variable list

Comment: @user3225087: Ok, I see that now.  Still the same problem though.  Think like the compiler; you bring in `list.h` because `init.h` needs the definition. To compile  `list` you need to know the size of `input`, but `input` is not defined yet, and around we go.